# Disable side by side DatePicker

Tags: android, datepicker

How do I disable side by side DatePicker shown in my activity (running under `KitKat/ Android 4.4`, I'm using `Sony Xperia` to run it), I've been struggling so much finding this one, the left side contains scrolled part and the right side contains full calender, I want only the full calender shown:

[image]

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class versi2 extends Activity {
    private TextView textViewTanggal;
    private DatePicker datePicker;
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.versi2);
            setCurrentDateOnView();

    }

    // display current date
    public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

        textViewTanggal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayDate);
        datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // set current date into textview
        textViewTanggal.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
                .append(year).append(" "));

        datePicker.init(year, month, day, dateSetListener);
    }


    private DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener dateSetListener = new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {

        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
            textViewTanggal.setText(new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                    .append(dayOfMonth + 1).append("-").append(monthOfYear).append("-")
                    .append(year).append(" "));

        }
    };
}
```

And layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 ....
 ....
    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/dpResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you want instead?

Comment: ... and of course you started from reading the docs? ... not? ... why? seems like few first attributes is what's you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DatePicker` has a [`datePickerMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#attr_android:datePickerMode) attribute.

Use `android:datePickerMode="calendar"` to show just the calendar.

Comment: Thanks @Tanis.7x, I'll search for that.

Comment: it won't work without `android:spinnersShown="false"`, but Thank you very much!